# How large are the reals in $[0,1)$ with defined asymptotic density?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, cardinals

Given some set of natural numbers, we can sometimes define that set's [asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density). The asymptotic density of a set will always lie in the interval $[0,1]$.

Since we can map sets of natural numbers onto real numbers in $[0,1)$ via the binary expansion, and vice versa (always using the terminating binary expansion when possible), we can thus speak of the asymptotic density of a real number.

Then, for some density $0 \leq d \leq 1$, we can construct the set of all real numbers $\Bbb R_d$ with asymptotic density = $d$. We can also construct the set of real numbers where the asymptotic density is undefined, denoted here by $\Bbb R_\times$.

Here are my questions:

1. What are the cardinalities of the individual $\Bbb R_d$?
2. Are all of the $\Bbb R_d$ measurable? (And if so, presumably, all of measure zero?)
3. What is the cardinality of the set $\Bbb R_\times$?
4. Is the set $\Bbb R_\times$ measurable, and if so, what is its measure?

Partly I am curious which of these things are provable in ZFC, or which might be related to things like CH. I am also very interested in seeing how the picture might change if the axiom of choice is dropped.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb R_{1/2}$ of full measure, and all the other $\mathbb R_d$ of zero measure?

Comment: @kimchilover: why would $\mathbb R_{1/2}$ be of full measure and not of zero measure? I would guess $\mathbb R_{\times}$ might be of full measure

Comment: Because of Borel's  [Normal Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).  Most reals in $[0,1]$ have binary expansions that look like sequences of independent fair coin flips, in senses that can be made precise. Basically, Borel's point of view was that the unit interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure is measure-theoretically isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ with product fair-coin toss measure.  If so, the strong law of large numbers gets $\mu(\mathbb R_{1/2})=1$ and so on.

Comment: It's also not hard to show that each $\mathbb{R}_d$ has size continuum (think about what effect changing the $n^2$th bit of a binary sequence, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, will have on the asymptotic density ...).

Comment: That makes sense that you could use the normal number theorem to show that, though somewhat strange that almost all sets of natural numbers have a defined natural density equal to 1/2!

Comment: Actually, this still isn't right - the set of reals with density equal to 1/2 is larger than the set of normal numbers, as it doesn't require each substring to be represented in equal quantities, and only applies to base 2. So it may be the case that this set is too large to be measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the normal number theorem, we have that the *outer* measure of $\mathbb{R}_{1\over 2}$ is $1$. Of course, this leaves open the question of whether $\mathbb{R}_{1\over 2}$ is actually measurable.

The measurability of $\mathbb{R}_{1\over 2}$ is a consequence of a much stronger fact: that $\mathbb{R}_{1\over 2}$ is Borel (in fact $\Pi^0_3$ - the same complexity as the set of normal numbers). This finishes the job since every Borel set is of course measurable.

---

In fact, *every* one of the sets you mention is Borel.